# Get page insights and post insights in the same request

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Hello i am trying to get page level insights and post level insights in the same request but cant seem to get the syntax correct.

`page id  /published_posts?fields=permalink_url,created_time,message,shares,reactions.limit(0).summary(1),comments.limit(0).summary(1),insights.metric(post_reactions_by_type_total,post_impressions_unique,page_posts_impressions_organic)&since=yesterday`

This is my request for now but i wanna add page insights like page_fans and page_fans_city.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `published_posts` endpoint there already, you can not go back “up” to the page object from there. You need to rewrite the whole thing so that you use the page id itself as the basic endpoint, and then request everything else via the `fields` parameter. The trick is to get the syntax and nesting right …

```
/page-id?fields=insights.metric(page_fans,page_fans_city),published_posts{…}
```

should work, inside the `{…}` you then put all the original fields you requested from the published_posts endpoint before, so

```
/page-id?fields=insights.metric(page_fans,page_fans_city),published_posts{permalink_url,
    created_time,…,insights.metric(post_reactions_by_type_total,post_impressions_unique,
                                   page_posts_impressions_organic)}
```

<del>And `&since=yesterday` then just goes at the end again, after all that.</del>

To have the `since` limitation still apply on the post level, it apparently needs to be added on that “field” again, syntax similar to `.metric()`:

```
?fields=…,published_posts.since(yesterday){…}
```

Comment: Hey @CBroe, thanks very much for this. Works perfectly apart from the &since=yesterday part which doesn't seem to work as intended. It retrieves posts from 2 weeks ago. Any thoughts what might be the issue with that?

Comment: Yeah, I thought that part might be problematic, right now it probably applies to the page object, where it makes rather little sense. But I think you should be able to “chain” this in similar to `.metric()`, same pseudo-function syntax. Can you give `?fields=published_posts.since(yesterday){…}` a try, please? I don’t have access to a page with enough relevant data to test right now. (It has to be in that order, `published_posts{…}.since(yesterday)` would cause a syntax error.)